# MDM commands not reaching to iPhone

Tags: ios, mdm, ios15

I am working on an enterprise application which runs on supervised devices.

It uses MDM commands to perform certain operation for which we created our own MDM server and communication between our devices and mdm was happening smoothly till last month.

Last month our MDM server certificate got expired so as usual we renewed the MDM certificate along with APN certificate, after this the communication between the APNS and device has stopped.
Basically our logs show that MDM command is reaching the APNS but APNS is not able to wake up the device and device polling is not working, so none of the MDM commands are working.

We tried creating new MDM and APNS certificates as well with our enterprise account but the result is still the same.

So my questions are

**Can we debug the APNS and device communication?** If yes then please tell how.

**Did anything changed with respect to MDM or APNS certificates?** If yes then a link or guide to create certificates and mobileConfiguration profile on a mac will be really helpful.

**Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you debug an iPhone connected to your MDM, you should see messages related to the push notifications. They appear in the debug console, which you can access using XCode. Is your MDM's SSL certificate valid? Are you use client certificates?

Comment: Hey Tomas, thanks for your comment but I am not getting any logs on device. Also tried to monitor network logs to check if there is any activity related to MDM but that also showed nothing. MDM certificates are valid and yes I am using client certificates to test everything.